# How to do regex operation with tensorflow string?

Tags: python, regex, string, tensorflow, tensor

I want to perform some logic on my text data, and basically I want to remove all text between two flags(A and B), i.e. every character between A and B will be replaced by space, how can i implement it with tf.strings?
TIA!

Comment: Welcome at SO. Please give an example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Can you provide an example code ? you can also  go through this  documentation on regex_replace - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/regex_replace?hl=en to see if it helps.